# Send blend file with vdb

Tags: export, blend-files, packed-data

I have a blend file set up with vdb clouds.

Now I want to send it to someone.

However, even though I packed the file and sent it, the vdb is not showing on viewport. It is appearing in the outliner.

On top of that, I also tried to send the vdb separately, and then gave the path of the vdb in the object data properties in Properties panel.

[image]

What is the proper way to send a blend file with vdb or better if access the vdb data when you send the file

[image]

Comment: Blender can pack only images and audio, but not movie or vdb files. What you see in Outliner is "only" an object (container) storing vdb external data. Your second options should work - send .blend file adn .vdb files. Receiver has to update (correct) path to actual location of .vdb files at his directory ... File > External Data > Find missing files ... or if you store .vdb files next to .blend file the path can be relative, so there is not a full path just double slash ... something like this //VDB/cloud###.vdb so receiver doesn't has to change path.