# Does blender support packing .vdb files?

Tags: packed-data, packing

Does blender support packing `.vdb` files? Also should Blender report if `.vdb` file is missing when you press `report missing files` ? We are having issues because of that. After rendering was done, we found out that one `.vdb` file was missing (it wasn’t shown in `report missing files`)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/279481/send-blend-file-with-vdb